# Kafka - how to know whether it is broker property or topic property or producer property

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am going through the documentation and often times, it is either not clear or need to look at in multiple pleaces to see to which a prticular property belongs and is it a specific property to an entity etc ..

To give an example, consider **"min.insync.replicas"** - This is just for an example. From the apache documentation, it is mentioned under https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs . From the confluent documentation it is mentioned  under https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html . Later, I came to know that this property is available under both and follows inheritance based on where it is configured. This needed to look into multiple places to understand more about this property to see where it belongs etc ..

But, is not there a documentation about where each property belongs, and will it be inherited or not etc.

I do not think this answer need not be complex like looking into source code, it should be simple enough - perhaps I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `kafka-configs` tool will list configurations in the console under the appropriate *entity-type*.

> But, is not there a documentation about where each property belongs,
>   and will it be inherited or not etc.

Under the default column you can see the default value. For example, `segment.bytes` ([segment.bytes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#segment.bytes)) property under topic has a column called `Server default property`

```
Server Default Property:    log.segment.bytes
```

and `compression.type` ([compression.type](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compression.type)) topic config has the default as `producer`

```
$ bin/kafka-configs
...

--add-config <String>                  Key Value pairs of configs to add.     
                                         Square brackets can be used to group 
                                         values which contain commas: 'k1=v1, 
                                         k2=[v1,v2,v2],k3=v3'. The following  
                                         is a list of valid configurations:   
                                         For entity-type 'topics':            
                                        cleanup.policy                        
                                        compression.type                      
                                        confluent.tier.enable                 
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.bytes     
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.ms        
                                        delete.retention.ms                   
                                        file.delete.delay.ms                  
                                        flush.messages                        
                                        flush.ms                              
                                        follower.replication.throttled.       
                                         replicas                             
                                        index.interval.bytes                  
                                        leader.replication.throttled.replicas 
                                        max.compaction.lag.ms                 
                                        max.message.bytes                     
                                        message.downconversion.enable         
                                        message.format.version                
                                        message.timestamp.difference.max.ms   
                                        message.timestamp.type                
                                        min.cleanable.dirty.ratio             
                                        min.compaction.lag.ms                 
                                        min.insync.replicas                   
                                        preallocate                           
                                        retention.bytes                       
                                        retention.ms                          
                                        segment.bytes                         
                                        segment.index.bytes                   
                                        segment.jitter.ms                     
                                        segment.ms                            
                                        unclean.leader.election.enable        
                                       For entity-type 'brokers':             
                                        log.message.timestamp.type            
                                        ssl.client.auth                       
                                        log.retention.ms                      
                                        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter      
                                        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.    
                                         factor                               
                                        log.preallocate                       
                                        log.index.size.max.bytes              
                                        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor      
                                        ssl.truststore.type                   
                                        ssl.keymanager.algorithm              
                                        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor     
                                        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds 
                                        ssl.key.password                      
                                        background.threads                    
                                        log.retention.bytes                   
                                        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm            
                                        log.segment.bytes                     
                                        max.connections.per.ip.overrides      
                                        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms       
                                        log.segment.delete.delay.ms           
                                        min.insync.replicas                   
                                        ssl.keystore.location                 
                                        ssl.cipher.suites                     
                                        log.roll.jitter.ms                    
                                        log.cleaner.backoff.ms                
                                        sasl.jaas.config                      
                                        principal.builder.class               
                                        log.flush.interval.ms                 
                                        confluent.tier.enable                 
                                        log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms     
                                        max.connections                       
                                        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size        
                                        log.flush.interval.messages           
                                        advertised.listeners                  
                                        num.io.threads                        
                                        listener.security.protocol.map        
                                        log.message.downconversion.enable     
                                        sasl.enabled.mechanisms               
                                        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds     
                                        ssl.truststore.password               
                                        listeners                             
                                        metric.reporters                      
                                        ssl.protocol                          
                                        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter     
                                        ssl.keystore.password                 
                                        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol  
                                        log.cleanup.policy                    
                                        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules
                                        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin 
                                        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir     
                                        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second   
                                        log.roll.ms                           
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.ms        
                                        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm 
                                        unclean.leader.election.enable        
                                        message.max.bytes                     
                                        log.cleaner.threads                   
                                        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size            
                                        max.connections.per.ip                
                                        sasl.kerberos.service.name            
                                        ssl.provider                          
                                        follower.replication.throttled.rate   
                                        log.index.interval.bytes              
                                        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms     
                                        log.message.timestamp.difference.max. 
                                         ms                                   
                                        ssl.enabled.protocols                 
                                        confluent.tier.local.hotset.bytes     
                                        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio       
                                        replica.alter.log.dirs.io.max.bytes.  
                                         per.second                           
                                        ssl.keystore.type                     
                                        ssl.secure.random.implementation      
                                        ssl.truststore.location               
                                        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd               
                                        leader.replication.throttled.rate     
                                        num.network.threads                   
                                        compression.type                      
                                        num.replica.fetchers                  
                                       For entity-type 'users':               
                                        request_percentage                    
                                        producer_byte_rate                    
                                        SCRAM-SHA-256                         
                                        SCRAM-SHA-512                         
                                        consumer_byte_rate                    
                                       For entity-type 'clients':             
                                        request_percentage                    
                                        producer_byte_rate                    
                                        consumer_byte_rate                    
                                       Entity types 'users' and 'clients' may 
                                         be specified together to update      
                                         config for clients of a specific     
                                         user.
```